# Amazon SNS is taking too much time to deliver notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, amazon-sns, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a backend deployed in Amazon Web Services. I'm having a problem of performance with SNS push notifications. I have already registered an application with my API key from Firebase.

When I test the notifications from SNS console using the "Publish to endpoint" button the message is delivered really fast:

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Hello world\" } }"
}
```

But when I push the notification using the SNS Api for Java using a Lambda function, the message takes up to 30 minutes to arrive. So I tried using the "priority" parameter from Firebase to make the message arrives sooner and it is taking now up to 5 minutes.

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"priority\": \"high\", \"data\": { \"message\": \"Hello world\" } }"
}
```

Since these notifications are pushed during a game, is really annoying for one user to get game updates 5 minutes late. Let's say that one player makes his move, and the other notices that is his turn 2 minutes later, but he gets a game update notification 3 minutes after about the game that he has already played, so he will get mad.

For all those notifications I'm using a TTL (time to live) of 172,800 seconds (2 days). What can I do to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Since I'm using threads to push the notifications the execution was postponed.

It looks like Lambda pauses the execution of any thread after `handleRequest()` method is completed. I had the same problem using threads updating objects in DynamoDB.

My advice is to use Threads only for multi-task jobs, but warrantee that `handleRequest()` reaches `return` statement only after all Threads have finished.